# Sql Query with not in clause of subquery to LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

```
   select * from user_user_connection 
where userid_from = 3464 and 
userid_to not in
(select userid_from from 
user_user_connection 
where userid_to = 3464);
```

Hi helpies I am new to entity framework.
I am trying to convert this query into LINQ query not able to understand how can I write the subquery with not in clause.
Also which one should be better join or Include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
    from a in user_user_connection 
    join b in user_user_connection on 
        new {From=a.userid_to, To=a.userid_from} equals new {From=b.userid_from, To=b.userid_to} into c
    from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where d == null
    select a;
```

is similar to

```
select a.*
from user_user_connection a
left join user_user_connection b on a.userid_to = b.userid_from and a.userid_from = b.userid_to
where b.userid_from is null
```

which should match your not in query.

if you want a specific `userid_from` you can add another where

```
    from a in user_user_connection 
    where a.userid_from == 3464
    join b in user_user_connection on 
        new {From=a.userid_to, To=a.userid_from} equals new {From=b.userid_from, To=b.userid_to} into c
    from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where d == null
    select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this maybe:

```
var list = userConnection.Where(user => user.useridto == 3464).Select(user => user.userid_from).ToList();
var list2 = userConnection.Where(user => !list.Contains(user.userid_to));
```

Probably can be improved since Contains take quite some time (maybe put the list in a  hashset?)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```cs
var query = 
   from uc in ctx.user_user_connection
   where uc.userid_from = 3464 && 
     !(from uc2 in ctx.user_user_connection
      where uc2.userid_to = 3464
      select uc2.userid_from).Contains(uc.userid_to)
   select uc;
```

Or via `EXISTS`

```cs
var query = 
   from uc in ctx.user_user_connection
   where uc.userid_from = 3464 && 
     !(from uc2 in ctx.user_user_connection
      where uc2.userid_to = 3464 && uc.userid_to == uc2.userid_from
      select uc2).Any()
   select uc;
```

Ov via `LEFT JOIN`

```cs
var query = 
   from uc in ctx.user_user_connection
   from uc2 in ctx.user_user_connection
     .Where(uc2 => uc2.userid_from == 3464 && uc.userid_to == uc2.userid_from)
     .DefaultIfEmpty()
   where uc.userid_from = 3464 && uc2 == null
   select uc;
```